# NodeJS + AppJS + Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, node.js, npm, node-gyp, appjs

I am trying to build the SQLite3 module into my project.
If I run NPM install sqlite3 it fails.  Here is my npm-debug.log relevant:

```
235 info install sqlite3@2.1.5
236 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
237 silly exec cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"
238 silly cmd,/c,node-gyp rebuild,C:\NodeWorkbench\AppJS Workspace\template\data\node_modules\sqlite3 spawning
239 info sqlite3@2.1.5 Failed to exec install script
240 info C:\NodeWorkbench\AppJS Workspace\template\data\node_modules\sqlite3 unbuild
241 verbose from cache C:\NodeWorkbench\AppJS Workspace\template\data\node_modules\sqlite3\package.json
242 info preuninstall sqlite3@2.1.5
243 info uninstall sqlite3@2.1.5
244 verbose true,C:\NodeWorkbench\AppJS Workspace\template\data\node_modules,C:\NodeWorkbench\AppJS Workspace\template\data\node_modules unbuild sqlite3@2.1.5
245 info postuninstall sqlite3@2.1.5
246 error sqlite3@2.1.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
246 error `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
247 error Failed at the sqlite3@2.1.5 install script.
247 error This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
247 error not with npm itself.
247 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
247 error     node-gyp rebuild
247 error You can get their info via:
247 error     npm owner ls sqlite3
247 error There is likely additional logging output above.
248 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
249 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sqlite3"
250 error cwd C:\NodeWorkbench\AppJS Workspace\template\data
251 error node -v v0.8.14
252 error npm -v 1.1.65
253 error code ELIFECYCLE
254 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have node-gyp installed, as well as python (3.3 I believe).  Thanks for the help.  I really need this resolved ASAP, so if you could point me in a direction I would appreciate it greatly!

Ideally, I would like to use Nano and couchdb for my project.  JSON from front to back would be great.  But nano was throwing C++ exceptions during run time so I had to recompile the stack and start over (it recompiled AppJS when I installed nano which I assume put some faulty extensions in and messed up the whole works)  My stack is as follows:

Database > AppJS (NodeJS included in this) > SocketIO > AngularJS

The point of this project is to assemble a stack that I can use as a replacement for server2go.  My company has had severe stability issues regarding server2go, including data loss and DB corruption (MyISAM with MySQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a great solution.  Persist works perfectly with AppJS, and has a great non-blocking sqlite3 driver.  Just in case anyone else was wondering